# Can't find input package - LWJGL

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I'm trying to use LWJGL in my opengl's project. I already added the LWJGL jars; native and src to the classpath, but I think i'm doing something wrong, because i can't find the input package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have LWJGL 3.  There is no Input class, you have to set the keyboard callback.

```
public class KeyboardCallback extends GLFWKeyCallback {
    private static boolean[] keys = new boolean[65536];

    @Override
    public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
        keys[key] = action != GLFW_RELEASE;
    } 

    //The keyCode will come from GLFW.GLFW_KEY_ and then whatever key that you want!
    public static boolean isKeyDown(int keyCode) {
        return keys[keyCode];
    }
}
```

Then set the callback:

```
private GLFWKeyCallback keyCallback;

public void SetKeyboardCallback() {
    glfwSetKeyCallback(keyCallback = new KeyboarbCallback());
}
```

Remember that the keyCallback must be initialized there if not you will get an error about the garbage collection.

If you are using LWJGL 2 then you need to reinstall lwjgl 2 here: http://legacy.lwjgl.org/.  Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LWJGL 2: type `Keyboard.` and a list of options will pop up (they are self explanatory) you can also use `Mouse.` (remember the capital)

If you are using LWJGL 3: sorry, I don't know the answer... I use 2 myself because there are a lot more tutorials on it and it helps the debugging :)